# how to create binding in code when the datatemplate is declared in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a datatemplate declared in xaml. 
for e.g.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="txtBox"  Visibility="Visible"></TextBox>                
        </StackPanel>             
    </DataTemplate>
```

I wish to set the binding for txtBox in code behind before the element is generated because i have different binding paths for different elements that get generated

I can get the template in the code behind as :

```
DataTemplate tmplt = FindResource("TestTemplate") as DataTemplate;
```

but i am not sure what to do next. How to get the the txtBox reference to set the binding.

Answer (score 3):

We have to remember one thing that Templates are not instantiated UI controls. They are streamed obejcts in XAML and are shared between UI elements. So if you edit a dataTemplate and change its stucture (by adding, editing, deleting an element under the template) it would change the one data template which is shared among controls. Thus other elements using that template will also be affected by the change.

Now lets address your issue of adding a dynamic biding to a textbox. You say each generated textbox will have different binding paths. So this definitely does NOT call for changing the data template itself!

You will have to access the text box and add dynamic bindings to it AFTER the textbox's is generated.

I see that your binding differs based on your "situation", so why cant you use TemplateSelector? Template selector will decide which data template (having one specific binding applied to the TetxBox) at runtime.

Comment: Well!!! I agree to what you say. But that doesn't solve my problem. 
The actual problem is that i have to display a grid. the cells of the grid can be either a textbox or a combobox which will be known at runtime. Also, the columns of the grid can change during runtime. I have the requirement of copying and pasting the column. For this i created a cell template. and the binding for the textbox -> text, or, combobox -> itemsource i wish to do during runtime. Since the maximum number of columns can vary upto 100, I don't wish to write different templates for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of answer - is [FindName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname.aspx) method.

example:

```
DataTemplate tmplt = FindResource("TestTemplate") as DataTemplate;
TextBox my = (TextBox)tmplt.FindName("txtBox");
```

try out this, it should help to get access to `TextBox` control. I think that you know how to bind to. If you want your DataBinding behave different way, use `MultiBinding` and `Converter`.

**EDIT**

```
public class GeneralObject
{
    private object someObject;
    public GeneralObject(object initObject)
    {
        this.someObject = initObject;
    }

    //If you want to bind to some text, for example
    public string Text
    {
        get
        {
            //I think you know which objects are coming as input
            if (this.someObject is SpecialClass1)
                return ((SpecialClass1)this.someObject).SpecialClass1TextProperty;
            if (this.someObject is SpecialClass2)
                return ((SpecialClass2)this.someObject).SpecialClass2TextProperty;
            //and so on.
        }
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**
One more possible way

So I remember, that WPF have `ContentControl`!

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=CurrentObject}"/>
```

But in this case you have to create number of `DataTemplate`'s, every `Template` for one class.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SpecialClass1}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SpecialClass2}">
    ...
</DataTemplate>
<!--and so on-->
```

WPF resolve `DataTypes` of `ContentControl.Content` property, and put to the `ContentControl` right `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I think FindName would be helpful only when we have the elements already generated and we pass the templated parent as parameter to the function. My requirement is to set the binding before the elements are generated using the datatemplate.

Comment: You can wrap your objects to 1 general object, which will have properties that will have the same names and provide needed data for your DataTemplate. see answer edit.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
I have already thought of these workarounds. But then i was just wondering if there is any possible way to edit the datatemplates already declared in the XAML.

Comment: and what the answer? is it possible?